# Displaying a list of all the items/widgets inside a ListView Kivy/KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Is there a way to display a list of the widgets or the items inside a list view? the items were also added by buttons, then next thing that i want to do is to display a list of the added items in another screen? how would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an `id` to your ListView and later on access it in your code where you want it. After accessing ListView you can just call `lstvw.children` (assuming you accessed it as `lstvw`). It will provide you list of all the children.